# Installation of wireless adapter driver

Tags: wifi, drivers, kali-linux

I am trying to install a TP-Link Archer T2UH AC600 driver to Kali Linux 2016.1 (4.3.0) and the compilation is failing. I downloaded the driver "Archer_T2UH_V1_150909" and then did sudo make within the directory of the driver and I get this message:

```
root@kali:~/Downloads/Archer_T2UH_V1_150909/Driver# sudo make
make -C UTIL/ osutil
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/Downloads/Archer_T2UH_V1_150909/Driver/UTIL'
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6.util /root/Downloads/Archer_T2UH_V1_150909/Driver/UTIL/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/4.3.0-kali1-amd64/build SUBDIRS=/root/Downloads/Archer_T2UH_V1_150909/Driver/UTIL/os/linux modules
make[2]: Entering directory '/root/Downloads/Archer_T2UH_V1_150909/Driver/UTIL'
make[2]: *** /lib/modules/4.3.0-kali1-amd64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/Downloads/Archer_T2UH_V1_150909/Driver/UTIL'
Makefile:527: recipe for target 'osutil' failed
make[1]: *** [osutil] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/Downloads/Archer_T2UH_V1_150909/Driver/UTIL'
Makefile:3: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

So what's immediately obvious is that that it is expecting to find a directory .../build/ that doesn't exist. I'm not sure how to fix this problem, any help would be appreciated.